# Having maven repository without using any repository manager

Tags: java, maven, repository

I am owner of OSS project, which is now using Maven. Since we use a lot of outdated (and not available on Maven) libraries I decided to use Repository Manager (Nexus) to make all this dependencies available.

My OSS uses Maven for building and dependencies management, but we never deploy any artifacts (end product is not library but an application). I usually put all new dependencies manually in public repository of my Nexus, so that other developers can get to it.

Now question is, do I really need to have Nexus running (I have resources problem on my virtual hosted machine, so Nexus needs to be restarted regually), since we never deploy or install anything to it? Would it be enough if I made root of this public repository available through Apache? I don't use GUI of Nexus and like I said we don't deploy to it. Would it be perhaps enough just to start Nexus after I put new dependencies into repository (for reindexing, if it's required)?

Andy

Comment: If you don't deploy the artifacts nor the dependencies you use than it is no OSS project...Why do you need to restart Nexus regularly ? What is the problem? Can you describe it in more detail?

Answer (score 0):

It's "possible" to run a maven repository without a repository manager, as it simply depends on the files being in the standard layout. See the maven docs for more information: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-repositories.html

> Internal Repositories
>   When using Maven, particularly in a corporate environment, connecting to the internet to download dependencies is not acceptable for security, speed or bandwidth reasons. For that reason, it is desirable to set up an internal repository to house a copy of artifacts, and to publish private artifacts to.
>
> Such an internal repository can be downloaded from using HTTP or the file system (using a file:// URL), and uploaded to using SCP, FTP, or a file copy.
>
> Note that as far as Maven is concerned, there is nothing special about this repository: it is another remote repository that contains artifacts to download to a user's local cache, and is a publish destination for artifact releases.